# Kotlin Dagger 2.11

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to inject Dagger 2.11 Retrofit in Fragment, but i am not able to inject,

1) The issue is  AndroidInjection.inject(this) needs DaggerFragment and i can not change the BaseFragment to DaggerFragment object because it causes issue while replace the fragment

2) I am little confused with dagger architecture too, as i have seen many demo code for dagger 2.11 or above, They are creating Module for each activities. so do i need to create seperate module and component to each activities

```
open class BaseFragment : Fragment()

class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
       AndroidInjection.inject(activity)
       super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onAttach(activity: Activity?) {
       AndroidInjection.inject(this)
       super.onAttach(activity)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        println("----Retrofit----"+retrofit.baseUrl())
        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)** instead of        AndroidInjection.inject(activity) in OnAttach method of fragment.

Now it should look like

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
       AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
       super.onAttach(context)
}
```